# quantile function given a distribution that is not in r

Tags: r, plot, distribution, simulate

I am trying to produce a quantile function(f_q) for a given distribution. Here are my codes:

```
library(GoFKernel)

f_cdf <- function(x) {
  integrate(fstar, 1e-10, x)$value/I
}
f_q <- inverse(f_cdf, lower=1e-10, upper=5-1e-10)

ggplot(x_plot, aes(sample=x))+
  labs(title="Empirical against theoretical quantiles")+
   stat_qq(distribution=f_q) +
   stat_qq_line(distribution=f_q)
```

When I do this, I get the following errors:

Computation failed in `stat_qq()`: unused argument (p = quantiles).
Computation failed in `stat_qq_line()`: unused argument (p = quantiles).

There is no problem when my codes for plotting and the samples I get from f. The reason is I can successfully get a ggplot when I changed 'distribution=f_q' to 'distribution=qnorm':
[the qqplot given a 'wrong' distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xmzh.png)

So, I can be sured that there are some bugs with my 'f_q', the quantile function. So, if there is anyone who knows about specific requirements for the 'distribution' parameter for stat_qq and stat_qq.line, that would be greatly helpful.

fstar is undefined at 0 and 5 and has a range between 0 and 5. I designed a rejection scheme to simulate from this distribution and I am trying to compare the theoretical quantiles and the sample quantiles by a quantile-quantile plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formal for the distribution function may need to be named `p`.  Try:

```
f_q_p <- function(p) { f_q(p) }
```

Then

```
ggplot(x_plot, aes(sample=x))+
  labs(title="Empirical against theoretical quantiles")+
   stat_qq(distribution=f_q_p) +
   stat_qq_line(distribution=f_q_p)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I get a different warning this time: Computation failed in `stat_qq()`: f() values at end points not of opposite sign. Do you have any further suggestions?